# Overnight from San Francisco to Fresno, CA

Tags: buses, amtrak, greyhound

I was wondering if anybody had any ideas on how to get from San Francisco at 10pm to Fresno, CA? Does not really matter how far off of being a direct route but no layovers longer than 30 or 45 minutes and the most direct preferred without driving.

Comment: Did you try asking Rome2Rio nicely for advice?

Comment: @Gagravarr does rome2rio have a time of the day option? Not to my knowledge, no.

Answer (score 2):

The question, do you really want to spend the night flying? Or pay a ton of money to rent a small plane. Because there are no scheduled flights into [Fresno](http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightStatus/flightStatusByAirport.do) landing between 11:15PM and 9:05AM. You can, of course red eye to say Chicago back to Los Angeles and then up to Fresno but what's the point??

Answer (score 1):

There are no night Greyhound buses or Amtrak trains on this route.

The best you're going to get, if time of day is the most important factor, is a United Express flight UA5835 which departs SFO at 8:10 pm, and arrives in FAT a half hour later.

If you can suggest to us *why* you need to travel at a specific time of night, we might be able to come up with other alternatives.

Comment: I have a class that gets out at 10pm, I can get to san francisco no problem in the morning but getting home is the issue and I don't entirely want to drive.

Comment: @cflies1121 That really constrains you, then. I see a few options: You can skip class, you can stay overnight and travel the next morning, or you can drive yourself. Traffic really isn't an issue at that hour, and it's easy enough to find your way there even without a GPS.

Comment: It's about a 3 hour drive with no traffic. I'm not sure why you'd fly if you had the option to drive, given the amount of time (and money) it would take to get to the airport, arrive a suitable interval before your flight, fly, and get from the airport to your destination. Flights SFO-FAT are mostly useful if you live in the Fresno area and are connecting from a longer flight to get home.

Comment: Fair enough I was just hoping someone would know of some secret commuter option as amtrak is only 33 to get there and driving every week kinda sucks.

Comment: @cflies1121 Fast-forward  years and travel by self-driving car.

Comment: yes that would be awesome!!